# One line of my code isn't working but I don't know why?

Tags: python

I have this code (for a calculator) where I keep getting the error "line 43, in add
label4 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)+float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

I can't spot what the actual error is though? Does anyone have any idea? Most of the code has the same format, but label4 is the first of the lines that has a float in it. None of the code has strings of text so I don't understand why it thinks it needs converted?

```
root= tk.Tk()
root.title("Hello Python")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(210, 100, window=entry1)

entry2 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(210, 140, window=entry2)

entry3 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(210, 240, window=entry3)



label1 = tk.Label(root, text='First number  ')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 100, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Second number ')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 140, window=label2)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text=' Result  ')
label3.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 240, window=label3)

def add():  
    v1 = entry1.get()
    v2 = entry2.get()
  
    label4 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)+float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
    canvas1.create_window(210, 240, window=label4)
      
buttonAdd = tk.Button(text='Add', command=add, bg='white', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), width = 5)
canvas1.create_window(90, 190, window=buttonAdd)

def sub():  
    v1 = entry1.get()
    v2 = entry2.get()
  
    label5 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)-float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
    canvas1.create_window(210, 240, window=label5)
      
buttonSub = tk.Button(text='Sub', command=sub, bg='white', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), width = 5)
canvas1.create_window(140, 190, window=buttonSub)

def mul():  
    v1 = entry1.get()
    v2 = entry2.get()
  
    label6 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)*float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
    canvas1.create_window(210, 240, window=label6)
      
buttonMul = tk.Button(text='Multi', command=mul, bg='white', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), width = 5)
canvas1.create_window(190, 190, window=buttonMul)

def div():  
    v1 = entry1.get()
    v2 = entry2.get()
  
    label7 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)/float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
    canvas1.create_window(210, 240, window=label7)
      
buttonDiv = tk.Button(text='Div', command=div, bg='white', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), width = 5)
canvas1.create_window(240, 190, window=buttonDiv)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: check the values of v1 and v2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't share your entire program and say "it brokey pls fix". I recommend reading through these articles for best practices asking for help here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The error as I see it is that you are trying to set a float to the `text` variable.

In the line

```py
label4 = tk.Label(root, text= float(v1)+float(v2),font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
```

You are trying to set `text` equal to `float(v1)+float(v2)`
Of course, a float isn't a string and that could be causing your error.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use an `try` block like so:

```
v1 = entry1.get()
v2 = entry2.get()
try:
   float(v1)
   float(v2)
except:
   # do something or just pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue (I believe) is with this part: v1 and v2 are strings

```
text = float(v1) + float(v2)
```

When a user does not enter a number, the conversion fails (cannot convert an empty string to float.
I would add the logic to handle this case:

```
v1_to_float = float(v1) if v1 != '' else 0 #or other forms of handling, like the try catch
```